How to get the right link using org-capture from the second level
In my org-roam setup, I want to document information about individuals. To do this, I created an org file named 20230501233516-persons.org, which contains two top-level headings: * Overview and * Persons.
Under the * Persons heading, I intend to list all individuals. I've created a template that allows me to add people from any other file using org-roam-node-insert (C-c n r i). This template also facilitates the creation of new person entries on the fly, and ideally, it should add a link to the person entry in the file I am currently working in.
While the template functions as expected in creating new person entries, the link generated points to the ID of the 20230501233516-persons.org file rather than the newly created person entry. How can I adjust my template so that it correctly links to the new person's entry instead of the 20230501233516-persons.org file?
Here is my template:
  (setq org-roam-capture-templates
        '(("p" "person" entry
           "** %^{Name|${title}}
:PROPERTIES:
 :ID:          %(org-id-uuid)
 :AFFILIATION: %^{AFFILIATION}
 :ROLE:        %^{ROLE}
 :PROJECT:     %^{PROJECT}
 :CAPTURED:    %U
:END:\n%?"
           :target (file+olp "20230501233516-persons.org" ("Persons"))
           :unnarrowed 1
           )
          ))

My system:
system     MacOS 14.5 Darwin 23.5.0 arm64 mac
emacs      29.1 EMACSDIR=~/.config/emacs/
           EMACS=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/emacs-mac/emacs-29.1-mac-10.0/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
doom       3.0.0-pre PROFILE=_@0 HEAD -> master a99c6b90 2024-06-23 17:15:51 -0400
           ~/.config/doom/

Org mode version 9.8 (9.8-??-39272e216


Did you figure this out? I have the same problem: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/82031/in-org-roam-how-do-i-capture-into-a-subtree-and-insert-the-link-to-the-newly-c

No, I gave up on it.... there was an attempt but it didnt work for me: https://github.com/org-roam/org-roam/issues/2446
