In Org Roam, how do I capture into a subtree, and insert the link to the newly captured node?
I have the following capture template:
    ("s" "scanner entry" entry "* ${title}\n:PROPERTIES:\n:DIARY_DATE: %^U\n:END:\n\n%?" 
    :target (file "scanner/diary.org")
    :create-id t)

This will capture into a file called diary.org and insert it as a heading at the top level.
I want to create an interactive function that will, after inserting this node, create a link to the newly inserted node.
This is what I've tried:
(defun mn:insert-node ()
  (interactive)
  (org-roam-node-insert :templates tangent-template))

where tangent-template is the template above.
This inserts the new node into the correct place, but instead of returning a link to this new node, it returns a link to diary.org.
How can I get it to return a link to the new node...?

I suspect (but have not tried to verify) that you need to supply the optional filter-fn argument of org-roam-node-insert, otherwise the argument list gets curdled. Try (org-roam-node-insert nil :templates tangent-template). See Argument Lists in the cl manual.

I verified and it still does not work, but I suspect that org-roam-node-insert is the wrong function for the job: it does not return the link, it inserts it in the current buffer and returns nil. C-h f org-roam-node-insert says": ... Find an Org-roam node and insert (where the point is) an "id:" link to it. .

Actually, inserting into the current buffer is what  I need (but yes, it could have been designed better). I've used it successfully in the past - but that use case had the file as the node, so it wasn't a problem.
